# Migrating to salesforce. Importing contact data only. I need accounts created and linked after a contact is created

Tags: trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow

We're going to use trujay's data2crm tool to migrate our data from Hubspot to Salesforce. Everything works as expected for the data migration.

What isn't working is creating accounts. Since we don't use Companies in Hubspot, all data is coming across as contacts only.

I have a process built in Process Builder that creates an account as soon as the contact record is created. This is working as I expected but I'm needing the final step to link those contacts to the newly created accounts. The Account name will be the same as the contact name, and will have the same phone, address, etc...

I don't want to export the data from Data Loader and run vlookups to take care of this. I'd want this done programmatically or from a process builder/flow since we plan on running this migration over the weekend and would want everything tied together so our end users don't get confused as to why they need to create an account in order to create an opportunity.

I've tried following [this video tutorial](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbiQlxlb4R) but it's for an older version of Salesforce and I can't seem to get it to work.

Any pointers?

**EDIT: we don't want to use person accounts since we have a hybrid business model of B2B and B2C. We are using divisions to segregate those two. Our business models are similar so that's why we want to go this route.**

Comment: If you're using an entirely B2C audience with no real need for accounts, beyond shoehorning the data to fit Salesforce's default B2B model, have you considered using Person Accounts?

Comment: Just yesterday, I wrote a trigger [for another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/330459/2984) that may serve you well. Apex or a Before Save Flow would be the ideal tools to use here, as they can create the records and link them in a single step without recursive database saves. If you don't want to use Person Accounts, you don't need to; just use a Before Save Flow or Before Insert/Update Apex Trigger and create/link the accounts.

Comment: My apologies, a correction is in order for my previous comment. It looks like you can't create records in a Before Save Flow, so an "After Save" Record Triggered Flow would be ideal. You could use it to create and link the account if you don't want to use code.

Comment: @Antonio see my edit in the question. We want to stay away from person accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this and needs help, I ended up taking the contacts that were created and made accounts by using their name, phone, and mailing addresses.

From there I did a lookup based on exact matches on name, phone, addresses then linked Account `Id` the `AccountId` to the Contact record. Worked great.